# How to include mapped fields subfield in result in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

For aggregation, I have a raw value of my field. But I can't access this value in my query. For example, in my case I have a `brand` Tommy Hilfiger and it's raw value tommy-hilfiger as a `brand.keyword`. How to include this value in a search results?

```
'body' => [
    'settings'  => [
        'analysis'  => [
            'filter'        => [
                'remove_spaces_inside'  => [
                    'type'      => 'pattern_replace',
                    'pattern'   => '\\s+',
                    'replacement'   => ' '
                ],
                'convert_spaces'    => [
                    'type'      => 'pattern_replace',
                    'pattern'   => '\\s+',
                    'replacement'   => '-'
                ],
            ],
            'char_filter'   => [
                'convert_amp'   => [
                    'type'      => 'pattern_replace',
                    'pattern'   => '&',
                    'replacement'   => 'and'
                ]
            ],
            'analyzer'  => [
                'slug'  => [
                    'char_filter'   => ['convert_amp'],
                    'tokenizer'     => 'keyword',
                    'filter'        => ['trim', 'lowercase', 'asciifolding', 'remove_spaces_inside', 'convert_spaces']
                ],
                'format'    => [
                    'char_filter'   => ['convert_amp'],
                    'tokenizer'     => 'keyword',
                    'filter'        => ['trim', 'remove_spaces_inside']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'mappings' => [
        'my_type' => [
            'properties' => [
                'brand' => [
                    'type'      => 'string',
                    'fields'    => [
                        'keyword'   => [
                            'type'              => 'string',
                            'analyzer'          => 'slug',
                            'index_options'     => 'docs',
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Upd.

In my case, I store brand in 2 fields: default "Tommy Hilfiger" for full-text search, formatted keyword (slug) "tommy-hilfiger" for exact search. I can aggregate data by slug, but can't get this field in my query. For example, this query return all records with brand Tommy Hilfiger, but only default values, not a slug.

```
'body' => [
    '_source'   => [
        'brand',
        'brand.keyword'
    ],
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'must' => [
                [
                    'terms' => [
                        'brand.keyword' => [
                            'tommy-hilfiger',
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Can you show a sample document, what you get in the search results and what you expect to get exactly?

Comment: If you are talking about doc in result, then elastic always return the exact document that was sent to index (assuming all fields are stored). So for example while indexing you sent `"brand": "brand One"` in result also it will return `"brand: "brand One"` irrespective of whether the field is analyzed or not analyzed.

Comment: @Val see my updated question

Comment: @NishantSaini see my updated question

Comment: I don't think that is possible because elastic returns whatever is stored in `_source` and that contains the exact doc which is sent for indexing.